# How can i access a class properties from within another one called from a IDataReader Func in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

i have 1 year experience only so please be gentle on me :)
I'm currently learning MVVM and i was following an example i found on net.
i tried to tailor it to do what i want it to do.
i have 4 classes (Models) that deal with driver,Students cars and so on
i decided to create a contact class  model that should be shared a cross all models.

i have a DataAccess Class with the following method to read from database

```
 public static List<T> ReadList<T>(string sql, Func<IDataReader, T> makeDataObject,
       Dictionary<string, object> parms = null)
    {
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            using (var command = factory.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = sql;
                command.SetParameters(parms);

                connection.Open();

                List<T> list = new List<T>();
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    list.Add(makeDataObject(reader));
                }

                return list;
            }
        }
    }
```

then i have a ModelDao for data retrieve as follow

```
            public static List<EscortModel> GetEscorts()
    {
        //string sql = @"SELECT EscortId, FirstName From tb_Escorts; select * from tb_Addresses ";
        string sql = @"SELECT AddressID,EscortId, FirstName From tb_Escorts
            inner join tb_Addresses on tb_Escorts.EscortId = tb_Addresses.AddressID ";
        return AdoDataAccess.ReadList(sql, MakeDataObject);
    }


private static Func<IDataReader, EscortModel> MakeDataObject = reader =>
           new EscortModel
           {
              // AddressesEscort1 = {}

               //AddressesEscort1 = { AddressId = reader.GetInt32(302) },
               EscortId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["EscortID"]),
               FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString().Trim(),
            }
```

and below is part of the class model containing the addresses model:

```
    public class EscortModel:ViewModel
{
    #region Fields
    private int _iEscortId;
    private string _sFirstName;
    private string _sSurname;
    private bool _bCrbCheck;
    private string _sCrbRef;
    private DateTime _expirayDate;
    private bool _bTraining;
    private string _sTrainingType;
    private Addresses _escAddressesModel;
    #endregion Fields

    public Addresses AddressesEscort1
    {
        get { return _escAddressesModel; }
        set
        {
            _escAddressesModel = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Get or set Escort ID
    /// </summary>
    public int EscortId
    {
        get { return _iEscortId; }
        set
        {
            _iEscortId = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

my issue when i try to access any of the Adresses properties from as follow

```
private static Func<IDataReader, EscortModel> MakeDataObject = reader => New EscortModel
     {
        EscortModel.Addresses.AddressID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["AddressID"])
     }
```

that is where I'm having the problem  as the reader only recoqnizes the EscortModel only but not the Addresses (contact).
         as the message will say firstchance exception
         any tip on how to access that Addresses properties within the EscortModel
         or there anyway that Addresses (contact) could be iherited by all other model bare in mind i have already viewModel is iherited by all
         by all model and as far as i know C# won't allow multi inheritance.
         thank you.

Comment: Your code seems unlikely to even compile! You are referencing the "EscortModel" by its type (meaning you only get access to members marked static) and then accessing the "Adresses" property (still a type, not a member). Is this the real code?

Comment: Hi LordTakkera, This is not the complete code i thought i only give part but if there is away i can attach the whole project I'll do so it is only 108kb

Comment: My point was, it doesn't look like you have valid code at the moment (the code you have is probably enough). Does it actually compile?

Comment: it does compile and run and display data from the database to a wpf window as well as to way editing is working the first name is displayed in a text box if edited it reflect on a list view. as i say i want to be able to add address details as i could that by declaring address details within each and every Model class that i have which i though in OOP is not ideal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I understand your question now:

It looks like you have blurred the lines between the Model and the ViewModel, and that is what is causing your confusion.

Your data objects (Escort in this case) should not be inheriting from ViewModel (since they are part of the Model). Rather, they would inherit from a base "contacts" class as you described. Of course, if you aren't in a "type of" situation, you shouldn't be using inheritance anyways. In that case, composition is what you need. To keep down on duplicated code, I would create a `ContactInfo` class that represents all the common information, and have each class have a property of this new type.

The actual "ViewModel" (which is one class per view) would then collate these objects for use by the View, and shouldn't contain any data specific to a piece of the model.

Hopefully that helps, let me know if I can clarify anything!

Comment: Hi LordTakkera, after i follow your advice i managed to pull all data available for EscortModel passed from DB but found that ContactInfo is always null now I need away to initiate contactInfo to pass the relative info any advise will help and thank you to point me to the correct direction

Comment: Whatever is initializing the EscortModel object should be able to get the information needed to populate the ContactInfo property of that object (and obviously instantiate it). Does that make sense? It seems like you are very close!

Comment: Thank you Lord ...Takkeka, i followed your instruction and my problem is that i wasn't initializing ContactInfo as observableCollection within my viewModel , now i got it to work and thanks for vital guidance...thanks God for stackoverflow..